# Configuration values wont set in Rails Engine 4.1.9

Tags: ruby-on-rails, configuration, rails-engines, initializer

I have an engine whom, in the `lib/` directory has a configuration file as such:

```
# Default configration for groups, roles and permissions
class Xaaron::Configuration

  # What is the memeber group name?
  attr_accessor :member_group

  # What is the memeber role name?
  attr_accessor :member_role

  # What is the admin group name?
  attr_accessor :admin_group

  # What is the admin role name?
  attr_accessor :admin_role

  # What is the can read permission name?
  attr_accessor :can_read

  # What is the can create permission name?
  attr_accessor :can_create

  # What is the can edit permission name?
  attr_accessor :can_edit

  # What is the can delete permission name?
  attr_accessor :can_destroy

  # Should we push this data to black bird? False by default.
  attr_accessor :push_to_black_bird

  # Defaults are set here.
  def initialize
    @member_group = 'Member'
    @admin_group = 'Administrator'
    @member_role = 'Member'
    @admin_role = 'Administrator'

    @can_read = 'can_read'
    @can_create = 'can_create'
    @can_edit = 'can_edit'
    @can_destroy = 'can_destroy'

    @push_to_black_bird = false
  end
end
```

As you can see I have set the default values, incase you don't decide to change these. Now in this engines `seed.rb` file I am able to do something like:

```
admin_group = Xaaron::Group.create(:group_name => Xaaron.config.admin_group, :can_alter => false, :can_delete => false)
```

And it works as intended, we see that `Administrator` is set as the group name.

Now I tried to create the following, in the app that this engine is mounted in:

```
Xaaron.configure do |config|
  config.push_to_black_bird = true
end
```

But when I booted the app, I got:

```
`block in <top (required)>': undefined method `push_to_black_bird=' for #<Xaaron::Configuration:0x007fbc6b305988> (NoMethodError)
```

Do I really have to define set and get methods for each of theses? I have seen other configuration files done in similar fashion.

Comment: Could you please share `configure` method code? Would be helpful.

Comment: @market, I am? Its `Xaaron::Configuration` Class. Does it need to be `Xaaron.configuration`? If so Why are my seeds working? Because if I do `puts Xaaron.config.admin_group` I get `"Administrator"` in the engine and in the app the engine is mounted in.

Comment: In Ruby `attr_accessor ` defines getters and setters, so you don't have to define them. The point is to see what this `configure` method does. Example code: https://github.com/markets/invisible_captcha/blob/master/lib/invisible_captcha.rb#L26-L28. Example usage: https://github.com/markets/maily#initialization-and-configuration

Comment: I dont actually have any kind of "`configure`" method set or defined.  yet its some how magically working when I do `Xaaron.config.admin_group` I can get the value, I just cannot set the value by doing `Xaaron.configure do |config| ... end` @markets - Should it be `Xaaron.initialize do |config| ... end`

Comment: Definitely it's not easy without see more code... is this Xaaron library open-source? Anyway, you're defining accessors for `Xaaron::Configuration` class, not `Xaaron`, so you problably should do something like: `Xaaron::Configuration.configure do ...`. Or may be `Xaaron.configure do ...`  is wrapping this inside, that's why I'm asking for that method.

Comment: all the code I have posted is all I have for setting up initializer. I found doing `Xaaron.configuration` to work. As stated there is no method, as you can see in `Xaaron::Configuration` called `configure`. Also this project is not open source.

Comment: In that case the `configure` method should be into `Xaaron` class (not into `Xaaron::Configuration`). Methods should be defined or injected or meta-programmed somewhere...

Answer (score -1):

Maybe this is the wrong approach but this is how I got it to work:

```
Xaaron.configure do |config|
  Xaaron.configuration.admin_group = 'Sample' # Prev: Administrator
end

puts Xaaron.config.admin_group #=> Sample, was Administrator.
```

Comment: In this case, you problably don't need to wrap the config into that block, since you're accessing to another scope (you don't use `config` variable inside the block). `Xaaron.configuration.admin_group = 'Sample'` should be enough.